RODR offset overflow count incremented_juniper_when fpc restarts
got this:
Jan 28 10:48:20.050 2010 Router_A fpc3 NFAB(3/1): %PFE-3: RODR offset overflow count incremented (1)
Jan 28 10:48:20.050 2010 Router_A fpc3 CMALARM: %PFE-3: Error (code: 542, type:Minor) encountered, cmalarm_passive_alarm_signal
Jan 28 10:49:32.063 2010 Router_A fpc3 NFAB(3/0): %PFE-3: RODR offset overflow count incremented (1)
Jan 28 10:49:32.064 2010 Router_A fpc3 CMALARM: %PFE-3: Error (code: 542, type:Minor) encountered, cmalarm_passive_alarm_signal
Jan 28 10:54:03.052 2010 Router_A fpc3 NFAB(3/0): %PFE-3: RODR offset overflow count incremented (1)
Jan 28 10:54:03.053 2010 Router_A fpc3 CMALARM: %PFE-3: Error (code: 542, type:Minor) encountered, cmalarm_passive_alarm_signal

per juniper:
When one FPC restarts, another FPC might report these error logs.
This is a normal behavior when restarting the FPC in one slot.
Each destination PFE uses its own set of sequence numbers to reorder the cells it receives from across the switch fabric. After an FPC has been restarted, the Nf chip needs to resynchronize cell sequence numbers before it can start processing traffic again. This message is transient and should not be seen after a few reports and traffic resumes.
can someone explain what does this mean in depth ++ info on Nfchip + nfab is greatly appreciated.

RODR offset overflow count incremented indicates that the Reordering Offset Register (RODR), which is used to manage sequence numbers for incoming cells, has reached a limit.
I’f I’m not mistaken, this happens during an FPC restart, as the Nf chip in other FPCs needs to resynchronise its sequence numbers with the restarted FPC.

As for cmalarm_passive_alarm_signal:
I believe this is a minor alarm indicating that the NFAB has detected an issue (in this case, related to the sequence number resynchronisation).
It is transient and resolves once the FPC is fully operational and synchronisation is complete, as you can see.

thnx for this, but can u explain what is Nfab and NFchip.
